# Store JSON data in NSUserDefaults Swift 2

Tags: json, swift2, ios9, nsuserdefaults

I'm new to coding. I have JSON request which returns different parameters, for example "unitid" and "buldingid".
i want to store the "buldingid" by NSUserDfaults. I use code below for storing it, but every time I get nil response for "buldingid".

reading:

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(buildingid, forKey: "buildingidKey")
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

writing:

```
let buildingid: [NSString]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("buildingidKey") as? [NSString]
```

i saved it in a label then stored in NSUserDfaults but it doesn't work (error: Attempt to insert non-property list object)

what should I do to get the correct response for "buldingid"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose from your code that `buildingid` is a String, so something like this should work:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(String(buildingid), forKey: "buildingidKey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Retrieving it should be done like this:

```
let buildingid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("buildingidKey")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It doesn't crash now :) I get this message in xcode log `PostData: buildingid=Optional("<UILabel: 0x7f9b99f99150; frame = (63 11; 0 0); text = \'hasan\'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7f9b99f64ce0>>")&year=1394&month=11`  and still don't get right response in app @Thomas

Comment: Oh, I see, buildingid is the label! That means that the object you're saving should be `buildingid.text` instead of just `buildingid` (in the first line of the code fragment above),

Comment: it's going better but still can't get the right response
this is what shoul i get from url:       
`{
  "Daramad": "200000",
  "Hazine": "0",
  "Mojudi": "200000"
}`

and this is what my log shows now:
`2016-03-25 09:37:09.252 Apa Pay[575:6361] PostData: buildingid=Optional("Optional(\"hasan\")")&year=1394&month=11
2016-03-25 09:37:19.259 Apa Pay[575:6361] Response code: 200
2016-03-25 09:37:19.259 Apa Pay[575:6361] Response ==> {"Daramad":"0","Hazine":"0","Mojudi":"0"}`

Comment: thank you I've added a ! to the end of writing code :)